In Snowflake, Best Practice of using : LAST_QUERY_ID() vs. Cursors for Capturing intermediate result in Snowflake Stored Procedures
I'm relatively new to Snowflake and currently working with stored procedures in SQL. In my procedures, I dynamically execute insert and update queries using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :InsertSQL. To capture the number of rows inserted, I've been using SELECT $1 INTO insertcount FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())); after each dynamic execution.
However, I'm curious if there's a more efficient or best practice approach to achieve the same result without relying on RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()). I've heard about using cursors as an alternative,
LET Res RESULTSET;
Res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :Insert_SQL);
LET cur CURSOR FOR Res;
OPEN cur;
FETCH cur INTO Insertcount;
CLOSE cur;

but I'm unsure about the trade-offs and which method is preferable in terms of performance and maintainability.

Use global variable SQLROWCOUNT to find the no the no of rows impacted by DML statement.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/dml-status

Actually, I executing the Insert/update queries dynamically. Where first I have to concatenate with some variables. Ex: query := 'INSERT INTO ' ||db||'.'||schema||'.'||table||'.....;, I this case I have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement to dynamically execute insode stored procedure. and SQLROWCOUNT not working in this case actually.

From the comments:

As @akshin says, the variable SQLROWCOUNT should work.
As @Tharun says, it doesn't work with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Snowflake insider knowledge:

This is a known issue that has a fix in progress, but you need to tell your account rep/Reach Support to apply the fix to your account before its deployed for everyone.

In the meantime:

I like the TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) solution (but I don't have an argument against CURSOR)

